# Time complexity of recursive function with a loop

Tags: algorithm, loops, recursion, time-complexity

What would be the **time complexity** of the below function?

```js
int f = (int n) => {
  if (n === 1) {
    return 1;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }

  return f(n-1) + f(n-1)
}
```

This is what the **recursion tree** looks like where `i` denotes the depth:

```js
                   f(4)                         // i = 0
                  /    \
                /        \
              /            \
            /                \
          /                    \
        f(3)                  f(3)              // i = 1
       /   \                  /   \
     /       \              /       \
   f(2)      f(2)         f(2)      f(2)        // i = 2
  /   \     /   \        /   \     /   \
f(1) f(1) f(1) f(1)    f(1) f(1) f(1) f(1)      // i = 3
```

Had there been no loop inside the function, the time complexity would have been `O(2^n)`. But now there's a loop so:

At each depth, the number of function calls made is `2 ^ i` and in each function call `n - i` iterations are done in the loop, hence at each level `(2 ^ i) * (n - i)` operations are being done. So, time complexity could be calculated as:

```js
T(n) = [(2 ^ 0) * (n - 0)] + [(2 ^ 1) * (n - 1)] + [(2 ^ 2) * (n - 2)] + ... + [(2 ^ (n - 1)) * (n - (n - 1))]
```

So am I right on this and what could possibly be the final time complexity?

Comment: Are you sure that the provided code is C++ and not JavaScript?

Comment: Each function call takes linear time, so probably 2^n times n.

Comment: @kiner_shah: probably not.

Comment: You have the right equation for the time complexity. You can just plug it into wolfram alpha to get the answer: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%282%5Ei%28n-i%29%2C+i%3D0..n%29 . By hand, `sum(i*2^i)` can be calculated as `x * d/dx(sum(x^i)` evaluated at x=2. You need to be careful about the limits of the sums which I've omitted in this comment.

Comment: The old-school way for recurrence relations is to guess the answer and then prove it. You can use wolfram alpha to replace the part when you have to guess (which in general requires experience in solving the specific type of equation you have, or work to plot numbers and get insight about the answer that way). You still have a valid proof once you've finished!

Comment: @PaulHankin how would you suggest without `wolfram` because you can't really use it in interviews :)

Comment: I gave a method in my comment. Yves gives a method in his answer. If you're being asked questions like this in interviews, presumably you have to be able to solve them by hand using traditional methods such as you've been given two of here.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the number of log calls is driven by the recurrence

```
T(n) = C1 n + C2 + 2 T(n-1)
```

with `T(1)=C3`.

We can guess that the solution has the form

```
T(n) = A 2^n + B.n + C
```

and by identification,

```
T(n) = A 2^n - C1 n - C2 + C1.
```

Finally,

```
T(1) = 2 A - C2 = C3
```

gives `A`.

Comment: Are you sure its just 2^N? If equation was T(n) = C2 + 2 T(n-1) it would be 2^N already, but here we have an additional N term.

Comment: @unlut: this was a typo. There is no `N` in my development.

Comment: @unlut: if you mean that the solution should have a term n.2^n, I say no. (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%2B1%29%3DA+n+%2B+B+%2B+2+T%28n%29)

Comment: I did not know wolframalpha could be used for these, thanks for that. I will find out what was my mistake in my solution.

Comment: @unlut: there is no need for Alpha, in fact. This finite difference equation is not difficult.

Comment: @YvesDaoust can you share some context on how did you derive `T(n) = C1 n + C2 + 2 T(n-1)` and from where did you deduce `T(1)=C3` and so on. I'm unclear on your entire solution :)

Comment: @VinaySharma: review the theory of linear recurrences (or equivalently linear ODEs).